# Google Maps using gmap3 not rendering correctly on Chrome Browser 18 on Android Tablet

Tags: android, google-maps, google-chrome

Is anyone having a problem with how Chrome Browser 18 is rendering a Google Map rendered using gmap3 jquery plugin on Android tablet (Samsung Tab 2 10.1 running Android 4.1.1).

My map will render fine on the Android native web browser but not in Chrome. It's really weird.  It will only load about a quarter of the map and the rest will be white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - this is really stupid but the parent div of where the gmaps was rendering the map had overflow:hidden on it. I removed this CSS rule and it works fine. I can't believe it. I don't know why this works and why Chrome 18 on Android Tablets don't work with that but just FYI this worked.